# Not able to connect to Postgres database in Visual Studio 17 using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Postgres version 9.3, my application is using this connection string

```
Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE(x64)};Server=IP address;Database=myDataBase;
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

while trying to open connection in visual studio I get following error:

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I have setup my ODBC Data Source in Administrative tool correctly and it is giving Connection Successfull message. I have setup both 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: Do you need to use ODBC? It probably would be much better using Npgsql

Comment: The few examples I just looked at all include `Port=5432;` in the connection string.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes I tried including port as well.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen haven't tried with Npgsql but it is working with ODBC on my production server but I'm having issues on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2017 itself is a 32 bit application, so to connect to your DB in VS, you would need the 32 bits driver (`PostgreSQL UNICODE`).

Note that this apply to Visual Studio itself (VS functions and extensions). It is NOT related to the application you are building, which can be either 32 or 64 bits.